# fragments are overlapping on each other

Tags: android, android-fragments

Below is my code and the fragments are overlapping on each other. while I'm using the app for the first time the fragments are working properly. Suddenly they are overlapped on each other.Then if I close the app and again open then it is coming normal

```
final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment fragment2 = new NotificationsFragment();
final Fragment fragment3 = new ProfileFragment();
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment active = fragment1;

SessionManager session;


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);

                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                active = fragment1;
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                active = fragment2;
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_profile);
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                active = fragment3;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);

    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());




    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragment1, "1").commit();

}
```

Comment: Share your activity_main.xml code

Answer (score 0):

```
private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = item -> {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                       setFragment(new fragment1());

                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        setFragment(new fragment2());

                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                       setFragment(new fragment3());

                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);


        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment1);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }

    protected void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


       }
```